# (c#) DataAnnotation: how handle an attribute that MUST be empty?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I'm creating a model with a strong use of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and ExpressiveAnnotations.

But  I need a suggestion to handle this case:

If attribute1 has value "ABC" then attribute 2 is mandatory (attribute 2 is a string). And this is easy:

```
ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes.RequiredIf("attribute1 == 'ABC'")
public string? attribute2 { get; set; }
```

BUT

If attribute1 has a different value than 'ABC', attribute2 MUST be empty

How handle this?

I search in MSDN and other sites. I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom `ValidationAttribute` like code below:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmptyIfNotABCAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _dependentProperty;

    public EmptyIfNotABCAttribute(string dependentProperty)
    {
        _dependentProperty = dependentProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dependentPropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
            .GetProperty(_dependentProperty)
            .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (dependentPropertyValue?.ToString() != "ABC" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And implement on your model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [RequiredIf("attribute1 == 'ABC'")]
    [EmptyIfNotABC("attribute1")]
    public string attribute2 { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. 
But how to manage custom message? 
Something like 


`[EmptyIfNotABC("attribute1", ErrorMessage = "Custom error message")]`

Comment: Did you try your code above? I think it's good idea

Comment: Ahaha you're right